# NameError: global name '_' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

The code:

```
if (query_id, _) in hashtable[bucket]:
```

I expected this to work [like in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python), but instead it gives this error:

> NameError: global name '_' is not defined

`hastable[bucket]` is a list of pairs if that matters <sub>(which I doubt)</sub>. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just checking `query_id` ?

Comment: I am interested in pairs that have `query_id` as their first member and I am not worried for the second one @PadraicCunningham.

Comment: Then unpacking in a for loop as suggested is what you want, that or looping and using `if sub[0] == ..`

Comment: Yes @PadraicCunningham, that would work too, thank you! Oh, why a downvote? I searched before asking and I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `x in y` is not magic; it's basically the same as `y.__contains__(x)`. Therefore, `in` cannot search with placeholders; the left argument is fully evaluated. Instead, use

```
if any(query_id == qid for (qid, _) in hashtable[bucket]):
```

Comment: OK that worked and I understood why my code failed. Can you please explain what you did? :) Moreover, do you think that my question is so bad to have a -1 score? :/

Comment: `any` evaluates every element of its argument. The generator expression forming its argument yields True iff the first item matches `query_id`.

Answer (score 3):

In a for loop (like the one you linked) the variable called `_` is defined. As far as I can tell, you didn't define it anywhere. What did you expect `_` to represent?

`_` is just a normal variable name in Python, except in the interactive interpreter (where it represents the last variable output).

Comment: That should be a comment Matthias. I would expect the 3rd item of the top answer I linked to. Moreover, I would expect that `[tag:Python]` defines it automatically.

Comment: I am sorry, I updated it and hope that is better as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the concept where you use it only stores the last output variable.
I'd go with:

```
if query_id in (x[0] for x in hashtable[bucket]):
```